# how do i flush the write-back cpu cache?

Tags: caching, x86, x86-64, intel

I probably should read the Intel manual, but it is really long and I kinda get lost in it

http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf

I want to know how to make sure my writes are in main ram.

Or is there some write instruction that bypasses the cache entirely?

Comment: "I probably should read the Intel manual" - Correct. We are not going to read it for you. Stop being lazy.

Comment: @MitchWheat: would you respond the same if he hadn't written the first line? Frankly, it is a pretty heavy reading stuff

Comment: Unless you're building hardware, or possibly setting up DMA transfers (IDK if they are coherent with CPU caches), it shouldn't matter when your data hits main memory.  The cores in a multi-core system keep their caches coherent with each other.  One of the reasons Intel uses a large *inclusive* L3 cache in their designs is to make checking the L3 tags sufficient to tell if any core in that chip has a cache line somewhere in one of its caches.

Comment: Use memory barriers (aka store / load fences) to make sure writes are globally visible, and that reads see any writes made by threads on other cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use streaming (non-temporal) stores. They're meant to avoid polluting the cache (for better performance), but that also means thay would just write your data directly to memory so they can be used for reliability.

Either use MOVNT* instructions in assembly, or check if your compiler provides intrinsics for that.

MS compilers should support _mm_stream_ps/si/..:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531466%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

GCC might call it differently (at least the new SSE flavors), try __builtin_ia32_movntq/ps/..
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/X86-Built_002din-Functions.html

Note that data persistence is a large topic, if this is what you're aiming at it might not be enough and you should also make sure you have fencing sync points that guarantee these stores were completed before you can guarantee the data is safe.